# Deleted first 512 bytes of disk; how can I recover my data?

Tags: linux, data-recovery

I accidentally wrote a 512 bytes binary to the wrong USB disk with `dd` and the device doesn't show any partitions with `fdisk` anymore.

I thought all the data was gone, but `dd if=/dev/sdx | strings` shows that the data seems to be still there, since `dd` fortunately limited itself to the first 512 bytes. **Is there any way to recover it**?

The disk had two partitions: an ext4 (~4GB) one and the remaining of 16GB were formatted as NTFS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To restore the `ext4` partition and its data, I thought about creating one, disk-wide ext4 partition. This allowed me to get **access to the data** and retrieve information about the partition with `tune2fs -l`, as suggested by @thkala. This information looks very feasible and, so, unaltered.

Very interestingly, gparted is somewhat able to figure out the **actual partition size** as turns out from this warning it shows:

> *10.96 GiB of unallocated space within the partition. To grow the file system to fill the partition, select the partition and choose the menu
>   item:*

because 11GiB was roughly the dimension of the NTFS partition.

[image]

Notice the unused space that, IIRC, it was the space the ext4 had still free. The **unallocated space** gparted recognizes seems to be NTFS partition; now, **how can I restore that one too**, maybe by finding out where the first partition ends i.e. its total byte count?

---

Finally [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) handled that effortlessly.

Comment: Excellent. Please would you _accept_ your own answer so it's clear you had an acceptable solution to your question.

Comment: @roaina Yes I shall when the two day minimum opening duration expires.

Answer (score 14):

It depends on what exactly was there before, but it might be easy(-ish) to recover from  this.

1. Use `dd` to create a full image of your USB drive on a safe location.
2. Use `dd` to create a full image of your USB drive on a safe location.
3. Yes, please do keep a full image. Data recovery operations can often cause more damage than one would expect.
4. Try to remember what the partition layout on that USB drive was like. *Write it down*. It might help if you have system logs from when that disk (before being messed-up) is detected by the Linux kernel - quite often it will print-out some data about the detected partitions.
5. Use fdisk to recreate the MBR with the same partition table. *Do not format and/or fsck any partitions*.
6. Try to mount your partitions with the read-only (`-o ro`) `mount` option.
7. If it succeeds, try to copy all files over to a safe location and watch your terminal and logs for I/O errors - the typical way for partition boundary errors to be expressed is via out-of-bound accesses on the underlying device.
8. If the copy fails, restore the image and go back to step 4.
9. Did I mention having a full image of the USB drive before doing anything else?

PS: You might also want to have a look at tools like [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk), that attempt to automate the recovery process. But you should still get an full image first.

PS2: If you feel comfortable enough, you could also experiment a bit. If you can make a reasonable assumption for the starting point of the first partition, then you can use `tune2fs -l` to get the exact size of the first partition, which would allow you to hunt for the start of the second one.

Comment: #1: `dd if=/dev/sdx of=backup.img` right?

Comment: @black: Yes. You might want to put a `bs=...` option to increase the block size and speed it up a bit.

Comment: A good blocksize to use is `bs=64K`. TestDisk is definitely worth trying, and it can work on disk image files as well as on actual disks. Good luck!

Comment: Running `cat /dev/sdx >backup.img` would be faster than `dd` in many circumstances and certainly no slower in this one.